# Proper formula for this probability

Tags: probability

I have here a probability problem that I was able to solve without using any proper formula, i just made it up myself. I wanted to know the proper formula approach for this problem:

> Amanda has some cards in her pockets. In her left pocket she has 6
>   spades and 6 hearts. In her right pocket she has 2 spades and 3
>   hearts. If Amanda takes one card out of each pocket, what's the
>   likelihood that the two cards are the same suit?

```
Given:
 Left Pocket
6 spades
6 hearts

     Right Pocket
2 spades
3 hearts
```

What i did was:

```
( 6 spades x 2 spades ) + ( 6 hearts x 3 hearts ) = 30
( ( 6 spades x 2 spades ) + ( 6 spades x 3 hearts ) ) + ( ( 6 hearts x 2 spades ) + ( 6 hearts x 3 hearts ) ) = 60
```

which gave me an answer of `30/60` or `1/2`

I know this kind of approach would take awhile if the given were more than 2 from both sides, that is the main reason i wanted to know the proper formula to use regarding this. Any help or advice will be gladly accepted, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $L_1,L_2,L_3\dots L_n$ of suits $1,2,3\dots n$ in your left pocket and $R_1,R_2\dots R_n$ in your right pocket then the probability both are of the same suit is 
$$\frac{L_1\cdot R_1+L_2\cdot R_2+\dots +L_n\cdot R_n}{(L_1+L_2+\dots+ L_n)(R_1+R_2+\dots+R_n)}$$

Since there are $L_1\cdot R_1+L_2\cdot R_2+\dots +L_n\cdot R_n$ ways in which we can take out cards of the same suit and there are $(L_1+L_2+\dots+ L_n)(R_1+R_2+\dots+R_n)$ ways to take out one card from each pocket.

Comment: thanks got it now.  ( 6 x 2 ) + ( 6 x 3 ) / ( 6 + 6 ) x  ( 2 + 5 ) would give me the same result 30/60

Comment: @MarcIntes It is $((6 \cdot 2)+(6\cdot 3))/((6+6)\cdot(3+2))=30/60$

Comment: that is just a typo. i kinda feel exhausted right now. sorry